# How to order data member's/properties in the DataContract serializer with inherited or subclassed objects?

Tags: c#, serialization, datacontract, datacontractserializer

I am having an issue where the DataContract Serializer is not rendering data members or properties in the desired order.  I have a data contract adorned class that inherits from another data contract adorned class, e.g. it is the child of a parent, and I specify the sort order for particular properties.

I am not sure if there is a special configuration setting I need to utilize or how to accomplish this, even if it requires a custom sorting routine.

Basically I want a certain properties from the "ParentResource" to appear before some of the properties from the "ChildResource" when the output is serialized.

Ideal Property Ordering In Serialized Representation:
 - ParentProperty1
 - ParentProperty2 
 - ChildProperty1 
 - ChildProperty2

Current Property Ordering In Serialized Representation:
 - ChildProperty1 
 - ChildProperty2
 - ParentProperty1
 - ParentProperty2

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
namespace DataContractSerializationOrderingError
{
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(ParentResource))]
public class ChildResource : ParentResource
{
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public int ChildProperty1 { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public int ChildProperty2 { get; set; } 
}

[DataContract]
public class ParentResource
{
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Order = 0)]
    public int ParentProperty1 { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Order = 1)]
    public int ParentProperty2 { get; set; }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

What you want is `DataMember.Order`.

```
public class ChildResource : ParentResource
{
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Order = 2)]
    public int ChildProperty1 { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Order = 3)]
    public int ChildProperty2 { get; set; } 
}
```